# Normal subgroup where G has order prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $o(G) = p^n,$ p a prime number, and H is a subgroup of G, show that there exists an $x\in G$, but $x\notin H$ such that $x^{-1}Hx = H$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Well, what if $H=G$? Then there is no such $x\in G$ such that $x\notin H$.

Comment: @BRayhaun We cant have that $H=G$. We must have $H\ne G$.

Comment: Well @user104235:  we certainly can have $\;H=G\;$ and then your claim is false. You **must** require $\;H\;$ is a *proper* subgroup of $\;G\;$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can induct on $n$ :

Now if $N_G(H) \neq H$, then any element of $N_G(H)$ will do, so assume $N_G(H) = H$. Since $Z(G) \subset N_G(H) = H$, you can now look at the subgroup $H/Z(G) < G/Z(G)$.

Since $|G| = p^n, Z(G) \neq \{e\}$, so you can apply induction to get $\overline{x} \notin H/Z(G)$ which normalizes $H/Z(G)$. Now check that $x$ normalizes $H$.

Comment: What does this "$N_G(H) \neq H$" mean? I haven't seen that notation yet.

Comment: $N_G(H) = \{x \in G : xHx^{-1} = H\}$ is the normalizer of $H$ in $G$

Comment: @user104235 your statement is known as "normalizers grow" for p-groups. It is also true in nilpotent groups and in fact the property characterizes these groups!